# Join/Concatinate column text based on criteria

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a data set like this:

```
A B C
----------
1 A blue
1 A red
1 B blue
2 A red
3 B blue
3 B green
3 C blue
4 C blue
4 A blue
4 A green
```

And a separate table like this (this is already auto generated using UNIQUE()):

```
E F G
-----
1 A
1 B
2 A
3 B
3 C
4 C
4 A
```

I want to join text from column C and show the result in column G based on a criteria given in columns E and F. The result I am looking for would look like this (all concatenated/joined text should be in column G):

```
E F G
-----
1 A blue red
1 B blue
2 A red
3 B blue green
3 C blue
4 C blue
4 A blue green
```

Optional, not needed but would be nice: The delimiter between generated text is a line brake so each line is in a separate line inside the same row.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

place your first table (data table/ 1,2,3) in column A to C.
and another table (5,6,7) in column E to G

Enter below Array Formula in G2

```
{=CONCAT(IF(A2:A11&B2:B11=E2&F2,C2:C11&" ",""))}
```

you will get your result.

[image]

For earlier versions, we need to create UDF

```
Function ConcatUDF(rng() As Variant, ByVal delim As String) As String
Dim a, i As Long
For i = 1 To UBound(rng, 1)
    If rng(i, 1) <> "" Then
    ConcatUDF = ConcatUDF & _
        IIf(ConcatUDF = "", "", delim) & rng(i, 1)
    End If
Next
End Function
```

and we will get the result.

[image]

**Edited:**

I forgot to absolute the references. Please consider below mnetioned formula.

with Build in CONCAT formula for excel 2016

```
=CONCAT(IF($A$2:$A$11&$B$2:$B$11=E2&F2,$C$2:$C$11&" ",""))
```

with UDF for earlier version of excel

```
=ConcatUDF(IF($B$2:$B$11&$A$2:$A$11=F2&E2,$C$2:$C$11,"")," ")
```

Comment: FWIW: CONCAT is only available in Office 365 Excel.  It is not available in earlier versions.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks for review. Please check edited version.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, for the data set you used, shouldn't for A 4 the resulting cell G8 contain 'red blue green' ? Does your formula concatenate only 2 strings?

Comment: It will concatenate all possible strings. I forgot to absolute references. use this if formula..... IF($B$2:$B$11&$A$2:$A$11=F2&E2,$C$2:$C$11,"")